# Как добавить json в таблицу. Swift

Tags: json, swift, tableview

Учусь на iOS разработчика, объясняйте пожалуйста как для тупых. 
Имеется распарсеный json, путем структур и протокола Decodable. Мне нужно свести некоторые данные в таблицу. Для этого, мне нужно создать структуру ячейки и свести её в массив, насколько я понимаю. Как это сделать ?

```
struct MoscowWeather2: Decodable {
    var cod: String
    var message: Int
    var cnt: Int
    var list: [List]
    var city: City

}

struct List: Decodable {
    var dt: Int
    var main: Main
    var weather: [Weather]
    var clouds: Clouds
    var wind: Wind
    var sys: Sys
    var dt_txt: String

}
struct Main: Decodable {
    var temp: Double
    var feels_like: Double
    var temp_min: Double
    var temp_max: Double
    var pressure: Int
    var sea_level: Int
    var grnd_level: Int
    var humidity: Int
    var temp_kf: Double
}
struct Weather: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var main: String
    var description: String
    var icon: String
}
struct Clouds: Decodable {
    var all: Int
}
struct Wind: Decodable{
    var speed: Double
    var deg: Int
}
struct Sys: Decodable {
    var pod: String
}

struct City: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var coord: Coord
    var country: String
    var population: Int
    var timezone: Int
    var sunrise: Int
    var sunset: Int
}
struct Coord: Decodable {
    var lat: Double
    var lon: Double
}
```

Вот структуры которые используются для парсинга.

Comment: Как сделать структуру? Или как свести ее в массив (не очень понял, что это значит)? И напишите, если Вам не трудно, как Вы сами пробовали то или это и что не получилось.

Comment: чтобы вывести данные в таблицу нужен массив, я в своих структурах получаю прогноз погоды на 5 дней. один день должен быть элементом массива. Мне нужна структура, которая выдернет значения которые мне нужны, а не все подряд из распарсенного json. И каждый элемент массива будет относится к этой структуре. Ну, это я так думаю. Все что я пока что сделал: получил json и расшифровал его с помощью структур и протокола decodable. Дальше надо как то занести в таблицу. Если вы знаете как это сделать, то скажите свой способ, минуя то что я написал выше и исходя из того что у меня уже есть.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словом "Таблица"?

Comment: Какие именно данные из всего этого вы хотите вывести?

Comment: Таблица - TableView. Вывести хочу дату(календарную), темперутуру в эту дату и погоду в эту дату (например облачно)

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось гораздо проще, чем я намудрил. В принципе массив [List], который есть выше в первой структуре, и оказался тем уже готовым массивом который мне нужен и не нужно ничего более создавать, оставалось только правильно оформить это в коде.